# Where to submit CSS feature requests

Tags: css

Does any one know any official place where CSS feature requests can be made?

I would like to request that there be an 'inset' keyword added to the text-shadow property so we can have inset text shadows. This seems totally logical since it is there on box-shadow, why not text-shadows as well?

Comment: You can do it here in 2023 : <https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/>

Answer (score 3):

> Does any one know any official place where CSS feature requests can be made?

A substantial portion of the discussion of the W3C specifications happens in the respective [W3C public mailing lists](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public). For CSS, you'll want to subscribe to [www-style](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style).

> I would like to request that there be an 'inset' keyword added to the text-shadow property so we can have inset text shadows

There is already [at least one existing proposal](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2009Sep/0108.html) for the `inset` keyword to be introduced to `text-shadow`. Also, look for [recent messages in the thread "Possible text-shadow enhancements"](http://www.w3.org/Search/Mail/Public/search?keywords=&hdr-1-name=subject&hdr-1-query=Possible+text-shadow+enhancements&index-grp=Public_FULL&index-type=t&type-index=www-style) for a much lengthier discussion on this and other aspects of CSS3's `text-shadow`.

Comment: To join the mailing list, send an email with the subject line "Subscribe" to `www-style-request@w3.org`. You'll get a response with next steps.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking for relevant mailing lists at the [w3c consortium](http://www.w3.org/participate/). Also, getting in touch with the dev team for the major browser vendors will help as well.